# Reference between .aspx and .cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference

How can I build a reference between a button event on a .aspx site and a function class .cs?

This is the .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent1" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="contentText">

   <div class="row">
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
       <input type="text" id="name" name=""><br><br>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <label for="address">Address:</label>
       <input type="text" id="address" name=""><br><br>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
       <input type="tel" id="phone" name=""><br><br>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <label for="email">Email:</label>
       <input type="email" id="email" name="">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

And here you can see my class .cs.

```
public class Login
{
    protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        makedatatable();
    }

    private void makedatatable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
        column.AllowDBNull = false;
        column.Caption = "Price";
        column.ColumnName = "Prices";

        dt.Columns.Add(column);

        DataRow row;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Prices"] = i + 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Login class an .aspx.cs file, or just a .cs file? Each view in ASP.NET WebForms has what's called a code-behind file, which contains a link between the front-end and the back-end.

Comment: That's called registering an event handler.

Answer (score 6):

The `OnClick="Button1_Click"` attribute in your markup tells the system which method in the server side code to execute when the form is posted back due to the click of that button.  You can either rename your `Button1Click` to `Button1_Click` or add a nandler that *calls* `Button1Click`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ASP.Net Website, you are missing autowireup and codefile attributes in your .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="class.cs" %>
```

If it is ASP.NET web application, You would have a designer.cs file auto generated for you. Then in the aspx file you can Inherit the class name

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyNamespace.Login" %>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the way I going to do this. How I must change the code that asp will give me back the "TEst" string in the DataList1

Comment: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataList1.DataSource = "Test";
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
          
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
          
           <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
               
           </asp:DataList>
          
       </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>